# Best Firebase rule to allow read to any user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to find the best security rule for my firebase project where it should allow any user(A user who doesn't have an account) to read data but yet prevent the user from writing. In addition, the rule must also allow signed-in users to read and write.

P.S. My current rule does it already but firebase complains every day saying my rules aren't secure and could drive up the bill. So What's the best rule to achieve what I want safely?
This is my current rule.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read : if true;
      allow write : if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question should include the rules you have now that don't work the way you want, with an specific explanation of what's missing.

Comment: You're saying it already works perfectly, but Firebase keeps sending you warning emails you don't want? Just block the Firebase emails or go into Firebase notification settings

Comment: @AugustKimo but here's the thing, it is safe enough? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @DougStevenson Rule included

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Firebase doesn't know for sure if you fully understand that any authenticated user can actually write the **entire** database.  It's a common mistake - people often don't understand the implications of using wildcards at the root level like this.

What you should do instead is eliminate the wildcard and call out each specific collection to give it the specific permissions you want.  That will make it clear that you are not blindly assigning full permissions to the entire thing.